# Marathon won't launch docker container

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I have a 1/1 master/slave setup with the slave having 8gb ram 8 cpus.  I am trying to use marathon to deploy a docker container with 1gb mem and 1 cpu but it just hangs on waiting

I believe this is usually caused by marathon not getting the resources it wants for the task
when I look at my logs I see

> Sending 1 offers to framework
>   8bb1a298-cc23-426e-ad43-d440a2a560c4-0000 (marathon) at
>   scheduler-d4a993b4-69ea-4ac3-9e98-b54afe1e790b@127.0.0.1:52016 I0127
>   23:07:37.396546  2471 master.cpp:3297] Processing DECLINE call for
>   offers: [ 5271fcb3-4d77-4b12-af85-d94fd9172514-O127 ] for framework
>   8bb1a298-cc23-426e-ad43-d440a2a560c4-0000 (marathon) at
>   scheduler-d4a993b4-69ea-4ac3-9e98-b54afe1e790b@127.0.0.1:52016 I0127
>   23:07:37.396917  2466 hierarchical.cpp:744] Recovered cpus(​*):6;
>   mem(*​):5968; disk(​*):156020; ports(*​):[31000-31056, 31058-32000]
>   (total: cpus(​*):8; mem(*​):6992; disk(​*):156020;
>   ports(*​):[31000-32000], allocated: cpus(​*):2; mem(*​):1024;
>   ports(*):[31057-31057]) on slave
>   8bb1a298-cc23-426e-ad43-d440a2a560c4-S0 from framework
>   8bb1a298-cc23-426e-ad43-d440a2a560c4-0000

so it looks like marathon is declining the offer it gets?  the next line in the logs say that mesos is reclaiming the offered resources and what its reclaiming looks like its plenty for my task?

any ideas on how to trouble shoot this further?

edit: so got to dig into this a bit further and found the marathon logs.

Basically the deployment works if we do not enter any information for port mapping in the marathon docker section.  The docker container deploys successfully and I can ping it successfully from its host but I cannot access it from elsewhere.

if we set the container port as 8081 (which is what the docker container exposes are its application listens on) we get further in the deployment process but the app within the container fails to build with error

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
>      at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
>      at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
>      at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
>      at listen (net.js:1270:10)
>      at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
>      at EventEmitter.listen (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
>      at Object. (/usr/src/app/index.js:16:18)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
>      at startup (node.js:138:18)
>      at node.js:974:3

So I think we are further along than we were but we are still having some port issues.  I dont know why the container would build successfully on its own and with marathon with no port settings but not with marathon with port settings

Comment: Can you post Marathon logs?

Comment: Have you enabled the Docker containerizer in your slave config?

Comment: Thanks for the replies I will be the marathon logs later today. Yeah we initially couldn't launch any docker containers and then we enabled the correct cintaineriser and the busybot container launched but not our custom one which needed a little more resources but still well less than should be available

Comment: Can't find the marathon logs unfortunately, trying to hunt down where I should be looking in the docs

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`. More details you can find [here](https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/troubleshooting/)

Comment: added some more info, thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things to check:

1. On you slave: `ps aux | grep sbin/mesos-slave` should contain something like:

   `--containerizers=docker,mesos --executor_registration_timeout=5mins`
2. Again on slave check that there's a Docker Daemon running:

   `ps aux | grep "docker daemon"`
3. Make sure you've configured Docker network (in Marathon) as `BRIDGE`. With `HOST` mode you might get in collision with ports already used on host. This will allow mapping `slave:32001 -> docker:8080`.

   ```
   ...
   "network": "BRIDGE",
   "portMappings": [
     {
       "containerPort": 8080,
       "hostPort": $PORT0,
       "protocol": "tcp"
     }
   ],
   ...
   ```
4. When the task starts in Marathon you'll see the app ID like `myapp.a72db5b0-ca16-11e5-ba5f-fea9945fabaf`. Use Mesos CLI (`pip install mesos.cli mesos.interface`) to fetch the logs. There's a command similar to Unix's `tail` for fetching `stdout` logs (`-f` follow logs):

   ```
   mesos tail -f -i myapp.a72db5b0-ca16-11e5-ba5f-fea9945fabaf
   ```

   and `stderr`:

   ```
   mesos tail -f -i myapp.a72db5b0-ca16-11e5-ba5f-fea9945fabaf stderr
   ```

   `-i` allows you to get logs from inactive tasks (in case that the task is crashing quickly). If you don't catch the ID in Marathon, use `mesos ps -i`.
5. In case that the task is not starting, there's either not enough resources or some problem with Marathon. Navigate your browser to `http://{marathon URI:8080]/logging` and increase verbosity for task allocation. Then check Marathon logs.